# To use some hook instead of "PHP contextual filter code" in view

Tags: 7, views

Can anyone please give a solution on having a substitution of "PHP contextual filter code" for views, inside a module code?

Comment: I think this will be too broad for you to realistically get a good answer. There's a reasonable amount of code to write, and what that looks like will depend on exactly what you need to do. How far have you got? If you can provide the code you're using so far you'll increase the chances of getting an answer I think

Comment: It's already solved. I'll put my solution here so soon.

Comment: That was quick ;)